# Nginx log full of `NULL` characters

Tags: docker, nginx, logging, null, logfile

I'm running Nginx in a Docker container, and my error log keeps filling up with `NULL` characters, so it looks like this:

[image]

I had Nginx and PHP containers both set to output errors to error.log. When I set PHP to use a separate log file, I get fewer `NULL`s, but they still crop up, especially in the PHP log.

Has anyone come across this before, and is there a tweak I can do to prevent it?

Comment: This is sometimes sent by hackers that try to break in.

Comment: Thanks @Henry, in this case it's a local environment, so it must be something to do with the config.